# Sorting 2D Dynamic Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort a two dimensional dynamic array when row 1 is for product ID and row 2 is for the product price. I want to sort by product ID, and have the results displayed formatted with width of 5. Here is my code:

This section is fine and does what I am looking for:

```
void readData (int**, int, int);
void printData(int**, int, int);
void sortbyPartID(int**, int, int);

int main()
{
    int index;
    int **PriceSheet, rows, columns;
    cout << "Enter the number of Products, and then the number of values associated with the products:  ";
    cout << "For default values, enter 5 (FIVE ITEMS, and enter 2 (TWO Values: ID and PRICE). ";
    cin >> columns >> rows;
    cout << endl;

    PriceSheet = new int* [rows];
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        PriceSheet [row] = new int[columns];

    readData (PriceSheet, rows, columns);
    cout << endl;

    printData(PriceSheet, rows, columns);

    sortbyPartID(PriceSheet, rows, columns);

    return 0;

}

void readData (int **p, int rowSize, int colSize)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++)
    {

        cout << "Row ZERO is the Product ID and Row 1 is the Product Price\n";
        cout << "Enter " << colSize << " numbers for the row number " << row << ": ";
        for (int col = 0; col < colSize; col++)
        cin >> p[row][col];
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printData (int **p, int rowSize, int colSize)
{
    cout << "\n\nThese are the Products IDs and Prices as entered in the system:\n";
    for (int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < colSize; col++)
            cout << setw(5) << p[row][col];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

THIS SECTION IS WHERE I NEED HELP

It reads correctly and prints the unsorted array also correctly, but I cannot figure out a way to sort the array. Specifically speaking, I need help on the void sortbyPartID function. I would like to use bubble sort, and I cannot figure out how to get this function to work. Any help with the sorting function/algorithm would be greatly appreciated.

```
void sortbyPartID (int **p, int rowSize, int colSize)
{
    int swap = -1;
    int end = colSize;
    int sortedID = **p;
    cout << "\n\nThese are the Products sorted Products IDs:\n";

    for (int counter = colSize -1; counter >= 0; counter --)
        for (int index = 0; index < end ; index ++)
        {
            if (sortedID[index] > sortedID[index + 1])
            {
                swap = *sortedID[index + 1];
                sortedID[index + 1] = sortedID[index];
                *sortedID[index] = swap;
            }
        }

    for(int index = 0; index < end; index++)
    {
        cout << sortedID[index] << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    end --;
}
```

When I run, I get some weird results on the last section. Maybe I am missing something simple, not sure.

Comment: Use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a custom comparator (the second prototype in the list).

Comment: Don't use bubble sort!! N-squared run time makes your computer sad!

Comment: When you're swapping productID, swap the productPrice of same indices also.

Comment: Is expression sortedID[index]  correct? sortedID is a int variable. So what does sortedID[index] means?

Answer (score 2):

We can also perform this using do-while as follows:

```
bool isSwaped;
do
{
    isSwaped = false;
    for (int index = 0; index < end - 1 ; ++index)
    {
        if (p[index][0] > p[index + 1][0])
        {
            int swap = p[index + 1][0];
            p[index + 1][0] = p[index][0];
            p[index][0] = swap;
            isSwaped = true;
        }
    }
} while (isSwaped);
```

Answer (score 1):

`int sortedID = **p;` is not what you want, and should be removed. (I think you wanted `int** sortedID = p;`)

Your bubble-sort should be something like:

```
for (int counter = colSize -1; counter >= 0; --counter)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < end - 1 ; ++index)
    {
        if (p[index][0] > p[index + 1][0])
        {
            // std::swap(p[index], p[index + 1]);
            int* swap = p[index + 1];
            p[index + 1] = p[index];
            p[index] = swap;
        }
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/OEgrqQ)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but this still does not work properly. It is not outputting the sorted array, but just the first element of the first row. The elements of the second row also needs to print, and they need to be attached to each other. I am really lost here so any help would be greatly appreciated. This is the code I have thus far:

Comment: void sortbyPartID ****header same as above
{
    int swap = 0;
    int end = colSize;
    int** sortedID = p;
    cout << "\n\nThese are the Products sorted Products IDs:\n";

    for (int counter = colSize -1; counter >= 0; --counter)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < end - 1 ; ++index)
        {
            if (p[index][0] > p[index + 1][0])
            {
                int swap = p[index + 1][0];
                p[index + 1][0] = p[index][0];
                p[index][0] = swap;
                cout << setw(8) << p[index][0];
                end --;
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Indeed, just fixed the swap (to swap full line) instead of just first value of the line.

Comment: Thanks Jarod42, but I cannot compile/build with the pointer as suggested by the edit. Any additional help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @evoloc: Added link demo. (I had to change col and row).

Comment: Thank you Jarod. Much appreciated sir.

Comment: thank you so much! Quick question. Why does the output text on line 48 repeats twice, for the unsorted and sorted? I need to create three more sorting types, by product price then do ascending and descending on both IDs and Price. I can probably figure this one out however I can't find out where or why the output text is showing up twice (line 48 of the demo code).

Comment: This line should probably be outside `printData()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the entire thing by using objects. Objects allow you to handle the related data in a sane fashion. Also highly recommend are vectors instead of C arrays.

```
struct Product {
  int id;
  int price;
  vector<int> others;
}
```

You can then store your products in `vector<Product> my_products;` and then sorting everything with

```
std::sort(my_products.begin(), my_products.end(),
          [](const Product& a, const Product& b) { return a.id < b.id; });
```

You can keep the existing input/output format, but place the values in the right place. This way it's almost impossible to mess up the attributes and everything is easy to work with.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but one of the requirements for this exercise is to use arrays. I cannot get around that. I wish I could use vectors.